# How to use an OR (||) statement in TestCafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I would like to check if one of two elements exists (different ways of navigation) but I'm not able to make it work in any way.

I tried like that:

```
((await t.expect(commonElements.navDropdown.exists).ok() || await t.expect(dashboard.dashboardHeader.exists).ok());
```

or like that

```
await t.expect(await commonElements.navDropdown.exists || await dashboard.dashboardHeader.exists).ok();
```

but it always evaluates as false (falsy).

I tried that also in many other ways but these two seems to me as the closest ones to a proper solution.

Is it even possible to use OR logical operator in such case?

Comment: Please don't put answers in questions - either write a proper answer, or delete the question.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the problem was an outdated TestCafe version. I was using 1.8.2 version, after update to 1.9.4 the 'OR' statement works as expected.

Thanks for the help for everyone involved.

Answer (score 1):

The second approach looks correct and should work. However, in this case, the assertion won't wait for timeout. One of your elements should exist on the page exactly at this moment. You can use the "visible" property instead of "exist" to wait for elements to become visible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work :(

OR operator seems to be not working in this example.

`await t.expect( await commonElements.navDropdown.visible || await dashboard.dashboardHeader.visible).ok();`

Only first expression is evaluated, the test goes to another step with a result of a first expression.

Comment: Hello @Leszek Urbanik, If the first expression returns true, the [`||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical) operator should not evaluate the next expression. I guess the `await commonElements.navDropdown.visible` expression returns true because the test does not fail and goes to a next step. Could you please elaborate on the behavior you wish to achieve? Maybe you should use the `&&` operator that returns true only if both expressions are true.

Comment: The problem is that even when only 1st expression is false (2nd is true) the test fails.

When 1st one is true and 2nd one false the test goes on.

Comment: I think the problem is caused by this bahaviour:

the expression
`await commonElements.navDropdown.visible;`

evaluates to 'true', when it's true, but when it's false it doesn't evaluate to 'false'. Instead the TestCafe throws an error:

`Cannot obtain information about the node because the specified selector does not match any node in the DOM tree.

       > | Selector('h3')
         |   .withText('Dashboard')`